# Can I say this equation is right?

Tags: inequality, epsilon-delta

Let $a,b,c,\epsilon$ be positive real numbers. This $\epsilon$ is that you can see in $(\epsilon, \delta)$-definition of limit, thus $\epsilon$ is arbitrary though $a,b,c$ is constant.

---

Now this equation is given.

$a < b < c + \epsilon \ \ \ (1)$

In this case, can I say the below equation is right?

$a < c\ \ \ (2)$

---

I think it is true. Let me explain my solution.

(i) When $a<c$

Trivial.

$ $

(ii) When $a = c$

$(\mathrm{eq.}1) \Rightarrow c < b < c + \epsilon \ \ \ (3)$

Let $d$ be a positive real number and rewrite $b$ as below.

$b = c + d\ \ \ (4)$

Then (eq.3) becomes

$c < c + d < c + \epsilon \ \ \ (5)$

But, since you can lessen $\epsilon$ arbitrarily, if you decide $\epsilon = d - 0$, the relational equation between $a,b,c,\epsilon$ becomes

$c < c + \epsilon < c + d\ \ \ (6)$

$\Leftrightarrow a < c + \epsilon < b\ \ \ (7)$

This contradict (eq.1). Thus $a \neq c$.

$ $

(iii) When $a > c$

(eq.1) $\Rightarrow c < a < b < c + \epsilon$

This case isn't essentially different from the second case of $a = c$.

$ $

Thus $a < c$.

---

Could anyone tell me whether this solution is right?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: So you have that $a < b < c+\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon > 0$? If yes this would give you $b \leq c$ and then you can use transitivity of $\leq$.

Comment: @Bemte Thank you for your answer. The situation is this. There exists arbitrary $\epsilon (>0)$ and $N(\epsilon)$. When $n > N$, this is right. $|z| < \left| \frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}} \right| < R + \epsilon$. (I'm studying d'Alembert’ss ratio test.)

Comment: pedant: inequality

Answer (score 1):

Clearly taking limit when $\epsilon\to 0$ we get $b\le c$ hence $a\lt c$.

It is good as an exercise for you using trichotomy (by the order relation in real numbers) but it is not necessary.